# Spring JPA Query - JSON_REMOVE - Pass query index dynamically

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using **JSON_REMOVE** method for removing one field from my JSON array column. Below is the query I wrote in JPA -

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE Data d SET d.month = JSON_REMOVE(d.month, '$[0].revenue') "
        + " WHERE d.year = :year ")
void resetRevenue(Integer year);
```

The above query works. But now I want to dynamically pass the index value like -

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE Data d SET d.month = JSON_REMOVE(d.month, '$[ :index ].revenue') "
        + " WHERE d.year = :year ")
void resetRevenue(Integer index, Integer year);
```

When I try above I get error - `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 3.`

I even tried below query -

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE Data d SET d.month = JSON_REMOVE(d.month, '$[ ?1 ].revenue') "
        + " WHERE d.year = ?2 ")
void resetRevenue(Integer index, Integer year);
```

But got error - `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Ordinal parameter not bound : 2`

Comment: Please try with this syntax `@Query("UPDATE Data d SET d.month = JSON_REMOVE(d.month, CONCAT('$[', :index, '].revenue')) "+ " WHERE d.year = :year ")`

Answer (score 0):

The solution as commented by Kedar Thakkar worked. Using concat to append my dynamic index was successful and gave me appropriate result.

```
@Query("UPDATE Data d SET d.month = JSON_REMOVE(d.month, CONCAT('$[', :index, '].revenue')) "+ " WHERE d.year = :year ")
```